# ElasticSearch Multiple Type Values for Single Field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case where I need to store different data with data types[object, string] for a field in Elastic Search.

The mapping I have created is as follows.

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "someObject" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "dynamic" : "true",
              "properties" : {
                "addresses" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "type" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "value" : {
                      "type" : "object"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

While trying to insert the below document

```
POST /my-index/_doc
{
  "someObject": [
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "type": "postal",
                "value": {
                    "city": "Delhi",
                    "lastName": "Doe",
                    "firstName": "John"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "email",
                "value": "johndoe@google.com"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "object mapping for [someObject.addresses.value] tried to parse field [value] as object, but found a concrete value"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "object mapping for [someObject.addresses.value] tried to parse field [value] as object, but found a concrete value"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Please help here. I can't rename the field from **value** to some other name as this format is being used by our other APIs as well which are not using elastic search and are already integrated with other systems.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: This cannot be achieved just with mapping. You may want to look into ingest pipelines to conditionally convert string to object, so that you always have object type, but I'm not sure if this would satisfy your requirements.